# Can't bind to 'fadeInAnimation' since it isn't a known property of 'app-home'

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am trying to include animations in my navbar using Angular but its showing the error as below:

Imported animation package in `appmodule.ts` file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { SliderComponent } from './components/slider/slider.component';
import { HoverEffectDirective } from './directives/hover-effect.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SliderComponent,
    HoverEffectDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Created a seperate `animation.ts` file and exported as below:

```
import { trigger,animate,transition,style} from '@angular/animations';
export const  fadeInAnimation = 
  trigger('fadeInAnimation',[
    transition(':enter',[
      style({opacity:0}),
      animate('.3s' , style({opacity:1}))
    ]),
  ]);
```

Finally imported the animation module in home component in `home.ts` as below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { fadeInAnimation} from '../../animations'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  animations : [fadeInAnimation],
  host : {'[fadeInAnimation]' : ''}
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to add common module in your imports of appModule.ts after browserModule.

Comment: @SaudAnjum thanks for the suggestion.. tried adding common module still getting the same error!

Comment: can you provide stackblitz example so that we can help you more precisely.